# How to change Samba4 AD realm

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, samba, samba4

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server that runs Samba4 as Active Directory PDC. 
The server is called athena and its DNS name is athena.ad.domain.com.
The realm is AD.DOMAIN.COM and the NetBIOS name is DOMAIN.

When I look at my users, their usernames are username@ad.domain.com. What I want is that they have username@domain.com. Nothing else *has* to change, but can change if necessary.

I tried to change the realms in both `/usr/local/samba/etc/smb.conf` and `/etc/krb.conf` and then change the user's account to username@domain.com, but when I did that, I couldn't login anymore. So at the moment, I'm back to the previous (working) configuration.

Do I need to reprovision Samba (with samba-tool domain provision)? Will the users be kept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do in AD terms is set a custom userPrincipalName for every user in the directory, not rename the domain; domains can't be renamed without significant changes in AD (see the RENDOM tool) and I don't believe an equivalent to that exists for samba.

I don't believe Samba 4 supports this, so unless I am wrong you will have to "migrate" the user accounts, meaning creating them all anew on a new instance of a new samba domain with the correct name.

Comment: It's this I was afraid for. Good thing the server isn't in production yet.